# Express callback needs more parameters than (req, res)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

For an express app I'm working on, [my callbacks can only have (req, res, next, err) passed into them](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

This is what I had that worked.

```
function listEvents(auth, req, res, email, authURL = ""){
...
var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
calendar.events.list({
auth: auth, ... });
}
```

But my function definition must look like this:

```
function listEvents(req, res){...}
```

I can retrieve email and authURL from within the API call, but I don't know how to pass in auth which is created in the method of which listEvents is a callback. I am trying something like this:

```
oauth2Client.credentials = acctoken;
    var output = {
      auth: oauth2Client,
      data: callback(req, res)
    };
    res.send(output);
```

But I need to get the oauth2Client *into* the callback itself. This would just let you send both in the response to the chain of callbacks.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Comment: I actually might be able to answer this if what I am about to try works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oauth2Client.credentials = acctoken;
var output = {
  auth: oauth2Client,
  data: callback(req, res)
};
res.send(output);
```

With reference to the above code block you are assigning auth as oauth2Client.
You can append oauth2Client in your req object and use it in your callback function.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I will look into how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

So I've talked to multiple people and apparently my issue is that I was not thinking of the request object properly. As the above answer states, one can append fields to the body of the request. I have only ever prepared requests in postman up until this point - so this is very useful for me to know. This is almost exactly what I was looking for; I needed a way to give information to a callback without passing it in as a parameter.